# В скомпилированном коде grpc сервиса отсутствуют некоторые методы

Tags: c++, google-protobuf, grpc

Я скомпилил grpc код с помощью cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
project(GeoIndex)

find_package(Boost 1.74.0 REQUIRED thread )
find_package(LibCDS CONFIG REQUIRED PATHS /home/anton/vcpkg/packages/libcds_x64-linux/share/libcds)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
set(protobuf_MODULE_COMPATIBLE TRUE)
find_package(Protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "Using protobuf ${Protobuf_VERSION}")

set(_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF protobuf::libprotobuf)
set(_REFLECTION gRPC::grpc++_reflection)
if(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)
    find_program(_PROTOBUF_PROTOC protoc)
else()
    set(_PROTOBUF_PROTOC $<TARGET_FILE:protobuf::protoc>)
endif()


find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "Using gRPC ${gRPC_VERSION}")

set(_GRPC_GRPCPP gRPC::grpc++)
if(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)
    find_program(_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE grpc_cpp_plugin)
else()
    set(_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE $<TARGET_FILE:gRPC::grpc_cpp_plugin>)
endif()

get_filename_component(proto_file "../Description_of_external_interfaces/GeoIndex.proto" ABSOLUTE)
get_filename_component(proto_file_path "${proto_file}" PATH)


set(proto_src "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/GeoIndex.pb.cc")
set(proto_h "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/GeoIndex.pb.h")
set(grpc_src "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/GeoIndex.grpc.pb.cc")
set(grpc_h "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/GeoIndex.grpc.pb.h")

add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT "${proto_src}" "${proto_h}" "${grpc_src}" "${grpc_h}"
        COMMAND ${_PROTOBUF_PROTOC}
        ARGS --grpc_out "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
        --cpp_out "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
        -I "${proto_file_path}"
        --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc="${_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE}"
        "${proto_file}"
        DEPENDS "${proto_file}")

include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")
include_directories(${Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(../Cone/QuadTree/include)
include_directories(../Cone/web/include)
include_directories(../Cone/CDSHelper/include)
include_directories(include )
file(GLOB C_SOURCES "src/*.cpp")
add_executable(GeoIndex ${proto_src} ${grpc_src} ${C_SOURCES} include/DriverClientConnector.h)
    target_link_libraries(GeoIndex Boost::thread LibCDS::cds-s /home/anton/dev/techno_park/geo_index_service/Cone/web/Build/libcone_web.so
            /home/anton/dev/techno_park/geo_index_service/Cone/QuadTree/cmake-build-debug/libcone_quadTree.so
            ${_REFLECTION} ${_GRPC_GRPCPP} ${_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF})
```

Но на стороне сервиса отсутствует реализация класса ServerBuilder.

Строчка

```
grpc::ServerBuilder builder;
```

вызывает ошибку

```
Variable has incomplete type 'grpc::ServerBuilder'
```

Если брать клиента, отсутствует метода CreateChannel().
Причем классы самих сервисов присутствуют.
Вот мой .proto файл

```
syntax = "proto3";

package MailTaxiAPI;

message Coordinate{
    double latitude = 1;
    double longitude = 2;
}

message LocationData{
    string token = 1;
    Coordinate coordinate = 2;
    bool isDriver = 3;
}

message DriverLocationData{
    Coordinate coordinate = 1;
    bool   busy = 2;
}

enum OrderStatus{
    economy = 0;
    business = 1;
}

message Driver{
    OrderStatus status = 1;
    bool        children = 2;
    bool        animals = 3;
}

message DriverInformation{
    string token = 1;
    Driver driver = 2;
    Coordinate coordinate = 3;
}


service OrderService{
    rpc GetDrivers(GetDriversRequest) returns (GetDriversResponse){}
    rpc RegDriver(RegDriverRequest) returns (RegDriverResponse){}
}

message GetDriversRequest{
    Coordinate coordinate = 1;
    OrderStatus status = 2;
    bool        children = 3;
    bool        animals = 4;
}


message GetDriversResponse{
    repeated DriverInformation information = 1;
}

message RegDriverRequest{
  Driver driver = 1;
  Coordinate coordinate = 2;
  string token = 3  ;
}

message RegDriverResponse{
  bool success = 1;
}
```

Почему так происходит?

Comment: во-первых, зачем такие извращения в cmake? Он же поддерживает protobuf! Во-вторых, того что вы привели явно не достаточно для ответа на вопрос (например откуда эта ошибка, которую вы приводите?)

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, дополнил

Comment: Я что-то в упор не вижу, чтобы вы линковали grpc к вашему экзешнику

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, ${_REFLECTION} ${_GRPC_GRPCPP} ${_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF} ? Это в target_link, а это в add_exe.. ${proto_src} ${grpc_src} ${C_SOURCES}

Comment: встречный вопрос: а зачем вы столько всего понагародили? Зачем понадобилось создавать эту кучу переменных? Они вам нужны?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, я просто взял cmake list из примера helloworld и добавил к этому примеру свои библиотеки. Если вы мне покажете пример более лаконичной записи, я буду очень рад. Ошибка была в не подключенном инклуде. Не знал что кроме скомпилированных файлов нужно подключать еще что то, просто взять все инклуды из примера